# assigning an array to a specific index of another array

Tags: java, arrays

how can I assign the array "spider" to the array "visualone" at index [n][i]?
(the last line of code is where I am stuck)
Thanks for your time!

```
public class tester1 {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] spider = new char[]{'^','@','^'};
    int i = 0;
    int rows = 12;
    int columns = 12;
    int spoutLength = 12;
    int climbHeight = 7;
    int frameSpaces = 3;
    char[][] visualone = new char[climbHeight][spoutLength];
    for (int n=0;n<(visualone[0].length);n++){
        System.out.println();
        for (i=0; i<visualone.length; i++){
            visualone[n][i]={spider};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why the curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

Use: visualone[n] = spider; to copy the reference of spider to the nth row of visualone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because `visualone` is an `char[][]` 2D-array, so

```
visualone[n][i]
```

will be a single `char`, not a `char[]` array. I think you want something like this instead:

```
for (int n = 0; n < (visualone[0].length); n++) {
    if (some condition)
        visualone[n] = spider;
}
```